# Are IC rated recessed LED drivers safe to be in contact with insulation?

Tags: insulation, led, recessed-lighting

Sounds like a dumb question, I know IC stands for Insulation Contact, but I'm not sure if both the LED panel and *driver* can be covered in direct contact with insulation. I touched a driver today and it was *hot*.

I have these [Halo 6-in canless recessed lights](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Halo-White-LED-Remodel-and-New-Construction-Recessed-Light-Kit-Fits-Opening-6-in/1001772082). When I installed them I mounted the driver boxes on the roof rafters. I'm going to blow in more cellulose insulation that will cover the drivers.

The manual says

- cULus Certified type IC suitable for direct contact
  with air permeable insulation
- Not recommended for use in direct contact
  with spray foam insulation (reference NEMA
  LSD57-2013

Comment: IC also stands for Integrated Circuit which the dimmer circuit would have. What do the directions tell you your link is just a sales ad.

Comment: cULus Certified type IC suitable for direct contact
with air permeable insulation Not recommended for use in direct contact
with spray foam insulation (reference NEMA
LSD57-2013

Comment: How hot is hot? If you can hold your hand on the driver, even if it's uncomfortable, it's not really hot in insulation or electronics terms.

Comment: I could only hold it for 10 seconds.

Comment: yeah, you don't want to foam the driver in, but that's because the driver itself won't be able to cool if you do that = cooked driver